# How can I use SUMPRODUCT or another function to total an allocated percent of employee hours by machine code?

Tags: excel-formula

My Excel workbook has three tables:

Sheet1: Column1 is "Employee Name" with string entries. Columns 2-10 are {Machine1, Machine2, ...}. Each employee name row has a specific % of their total labor that needs to be allocated to each specific machine. Ie: John has 14% of his labor allocated to Machine1, 5% to Machine2 and so on.

Sheet2: Column1 is "Employee Name" with string entries, Column 2 is "Total Hours" that is updated daily with employee payroll hours for a day's work.

Sheet3: This table has columns for each machine (Machine1, Machine2, etc.) and needs to calculate the total hours from all employees (entered in Table2) that are allocated to each machine.

Please be understanding, I have never worked on a problem like this in Excel and I have no idea what I am doing.I have tried a SUMPRODUCT function but am receiving an #N/A error.

Sheet1

| Names | Machine1 | Machine 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 10% | 5% |
| Name2 | 14% | 10% |
| Name3 | 8% | 7% |

Sheet2

| Names | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 12 |
| Name2 | 11.5 |
| Name3 | 13.25 |

Sheet3

|  | Machine1 | Machine 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total Allocated Labor |  |  |

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet 1 - Staff Percents'!$A$2:$A$11='Sheet 2 - Hours'!$A$2:$A$11), 'Sheet 2 - Hours'!$B$2:$B$11, (INDEX('Sheet 1 - Staff Percents'!$B$1:$O$11,,MATCH("B1",'Sheet 1 - Staff Percents'!$B$2:$O$2, 0))/100))
```

Comment: Please mock up some small tables that demo your data and expected output.  [edit] you post to include that mock data in a markdown table so we can copy paste.  It will help us help you.

Comment: I tried to add tables. They looked right until I posted, now I am unsure. I am doing my best--so I appreciate your help!

Comment: Data structure question. Is the sequence of employee names always the same across the excel file? If it is, then we are looking at a very simple sumproduct((sheet1_ttl_prt)*(sheet2_hours). Or are you looking to match employee name to employee name which can be different every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and VLOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$C$4*VLOOKUP($A$2:$A$4,$E:$F,2,0)*($B$1:$C$1=I$1))
```

[image]

Comment: the SUMPRODUCT and VLOOKUP function you wrote works perfectly in a test sheet I built to work with that has the same simplified three tables as you. When I apply the same formula to the other tables in my workbook though, the function only works when the first row of % data is included. Once I expand the selection to include more name rows I get an #N/A error again.

Comment: Do you have errors in the range?

Comment: Or are some of your "numbers" stored as text.

Comment: I don't believe so. I checked that the range is absolute and all of the numbers are stored numbers, not text.

Comment: It is really hard to trouble shoot without seeing the issue.  And before you ask, no I will not download a workbook or open one emailed to me.